# Replacing domain in JENA Triplestore

Tags: sparql, apache-jena

I want to replace the server of all my subjects stored in my Jena based triple store.

I tried it this way but the server isn't replaced...

```
DELETE { ?s ?p ?o }
INSERT { ?s1 ?p ?o }
WHERE { 
    { SELECT (uri(concat('http://localhost:8080/', SUBSTR(str(?s),22))) AS ?s1) 
        { 
          ?s ?p ?o . 
          FILTER regex(str(?s), '^https://somedomain.org/')
        }
     }
}
```

When I only run the following query

```
SELECT (uri(concat('http://localhost:8080/', SUBSTR(str(?s),22)) ) AS ?s1) ?s 
{ 
  ?s ?p ?o . 
  FILTER regex(str(?s), '^https://somedomain.org/')
}
```

'?s' and '?s1' do have the correct values.

It seems like that '?s' and '?s1' arent available inside the DELETE/INSERT block.
Whats wrong with my update query?

Comment: Hard to say without a complete, minimal example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and including (1) which version you are running (2) which storage system you are using and (3) what the data is.

Comment: I don't think it should have any effect, but it might be much cleaner to use `BIND(uri(concat(...)) as ...)` within the `where { ... }` without using a nested subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a sub-query in your update and you only project `?s1` from your sub-query.

This means `?s`, `?p` and `?o` aren't visible outside the sub-query. Therefore when the `DELETE` and `INSERT` templates try to build triples to delete and insert all the triples they build are invalid (because not all the variables are visible) and so nothing changes.

To fix this you should either project all the relevant variables:

```
DELETE { ?s ?p ?o }
INSERT { ?s1 ?p ?o }
WHERE 
{ 
  {
    SELECT ?s ?p ?o (uri(concat('http://localhost:8080/', SUBSTR(str(?s),22))) AS ?s1) 
    { 
      ?s ?p ?o . 
      FILTER regex(str(?s), '^https://somedomain.org/')
    }
  }
}
```

Or follow [Joshua Taylor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor) suggestion from the comments.  This is actually nicer since it simplifies the overall query:

```
DELETE { ?s ?p ?o }
INSERT { ?s1 ?p ?o }
WHERE 
{ 
  ?s ?p ?o . 
  FILTER regex(str(?s), '^https://somedomain.org/')
  BIND(uri(concat('http://localhost:8080/', SUBSTR(str(?s),22))) AS ?s1)
}
```